# React Navigation Stack doesn't cover whole screen on desktop

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

I'm using React Native Web to build a simple Reddit Clone.
I came across this issue while using a StackNavigator from React Navigation.

The stack 'screen' seems to get calculated by the dimensions of the monitor, instead of the content. So when a screen before the currently navigated screen has a larger height than the current screen, the content is still visible 'behind/below' the stack screen.

My homescreen:

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
   <Button style={{ margin: 5 }} action={() => props.navigation.navigate('CreatePost')}><DText>Create post</DText></Button>
   <FlatList
      data={getPosts}
      renderItem={renderPost} 
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
   />
</View>
```

My createpost screen:

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
   <View style={styles.element}>
      <TextInput
         placeholder={'Title'}
         onChangeText={setTitle}
         value={getTitle}
      />
      <View style={styles.editor}>
         <SlateEditor setBody={setBody} />
      </View>
      <Button action={() => onCreate(getTitle, getBody)}><DText>Post</DText></Button>
   </View>
</View>
```

Here is an example:

[image]

I don't want to the user to be able to scroll on the CreatePost screen.

Comment: I just published a new version of stack which should fix it. Can you update and give it a try?

Comment: @satya164 Where can I find it? Edit: found your commit on the official github :)

Comment: Yep fixed! Thanks a lot for implementing this so quickly, really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by updating `@react-navigation/stack` to 5.12.6.

See https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/commit/da35085f1e3440f26eea800c892c88aec64d072f